Is it safe to drop a partition just after detaching it concurrently?
I am trying to automate partition management on my psql (version 15) DB.
I would like to delete old partitions to free some space in the db. To do so, i plan to detach it using CONCURRENTLY keyword so I do not need an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock on the partitioned table.
Once my detach partition concurrently run, is it safe to drop the table just after ?
Or should I wait for the concurrent detach to be done ? If i need to do that how can I ?
Thanks
I tried to run manually and sequentially the two commands and it worked but I fear that the behavior might be different in prod environment that is under heavy workload.

DROP TABLE requires taking an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock on the parent table. As long as the partition is still part of a parent table, you can't drop it the partition without an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock. So Yes, you have to wait until the detachment was successful

Ok thanks. And how can i check that detachment is successful ? Do i have to do some kind of polling ? What are the best practices when trying to automate this kind of task ?

@RémiPradal Since the partition is locked exclusively by the detachment operation, I think your drop attempt will hang and wait on its own until that lock is released. No need to poll.

ALTER TABLE ... DETACH PARTITION CONCURRENTLY is complete as soon as that statement has finished. Since DROP TABLE requires an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock, an attempt to drop the partition before ALTER TABLE ... DETACH PARTITION CONCURRENTLY is done will cause DROP TABLE to block.
So simply wait until ALTER TABLE ... DETACH PARTITION CONCURRENTLY is done, then run DROP TABLE to get rid of the partition.
